# Custom rendering logic on server side + MVC + Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rendering, server-side

I have some rendering logic for custom markup (a'la bbcode, but *not* bbcode). So that when I'm getting the stuff from DB I'm then calling MyRender.ToHTML(model.text)...

Now what I do today is I just have a form below and I do a post and add the item and return the same view. My question is - how to do it with ajax? Should I create a control and return HTML a'la winforms? Is that sexy? How do you do something like that? Or should I drop it? Maybe duplicate the rendering logic with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is the easiest way to accomplish this. The way that would work with an MVC:

1 => Catch the form submit with jQuery

```
$('#id_of_form').submit(function() {
  // do stuff

  // at the end, prevent the normal submit
  return false;
});
```

2 => Send the form data to your Controller, e.g.:

```
// do stuff
$.post('your_controller.asp', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
  // do stuff with the returned data  
});
```

More info on how this works: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

3 => In your Controller you see that the form is submitted, and you send the data to the Model where it gets processed. Then the Controller takes the submitted text with the bb-like-code and formats it. After that you echo/display the formatted text.

Everything that's being returned after calling `your_controller.asp` (in this case that should be the formatted text) will be stored in the variable `data`. You can then use that data and tell jQuery to add it to the page in a specific element (e.g. a `div` below the form that shows what you posted):

```
// do stuff with the returned data
$('#id_of_result_element').html(data);
```